# How to detect if String contains url and make url clickable using javascript react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi guys am trying to detect if a string contains url and if yes wrap it using anchor tags and make it click able. but what i have display both the string and the anchor tags.

**My code**

```
function urlify(text) {
        var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
        
        return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
            var hyperlink = url;
            if(!hyperlink.match('^https?:\/\/')){
                hyperlink = 'http://' + hyperlink;
            }
          return '<a className="blue" href="' + url + '" rel="noopener" noreferrer>' + url + '</a>'

        })
        // or alternatively
        
      }
```

**Inside my html code**

```
<p>{urlify(text)}</p>
```

**output**

```
first remove anchors before return text.replace – Muneeb Mirza <a className="blue" href="https://onlyfans.com/my/notifications">https://onlyfans.com/my/notifications</a>
```

Instead of displaying the link with the anchor tags i want to display it as clickable link without the tags.

Comment: Maybe use an existing component like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `urlify` function is working as you expect, the result should be considered an HTML string. Use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to set the inner text of the `p` tag.

Example:

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: urlify(text) }} />
```

As the name suggests, this is potentially a dangerous function, but if you've full control over the content and computing the HTML tags that are generated, it's probably pretty safe.

If you've any concern over the content though then I suggest also using [DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) to help sanitize the `text` value before you process it to create the links.